# Broadcom B4318 driver not appearing in Additional Drivers

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm trying to install the broadcom B4318 drivers by following this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Installing_b43_drivers.

I successfully run Step 1, and see it install a bunch of things.  I can see it's created a /lib/firmware/b43 directory which is packed with things.

But when I try to follow Step 2, which says I should use the "Additional Drivers" program, I don't see the b43 driver appearing anywhere.  In fact it's completely blank.

I'm at a bit of a loss.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, having just installed it yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Type in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43-lpphy-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer bcmwl*
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer bcmwl*
```

Then reboot

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps re install your drivers which should not take long Do this via a terminal and you should see if anything goes wrong

So in a terminal type the following

```
sudo apt-get remove b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

This should reinstall your wifi driver

Alternatively what I have done is install the other broadcom proprietry driver STA

This was just as easy again via the terminal

Clear out any older files

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get install  bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Let us know how you get on as this should be easy enough with a bit of help

Comment: This didn't have any effect for me unfortunately. I'm seeing other threads saying that the b43 may be black listed.

Comment: ok perhaps you can check in a terminal with sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and uncheck or remove it if the B43 is blacklisted. Then repeat what you did above

Comment: Sadly, still nothing.  Commands are executing fine, but the Additional Drivers box is still showing "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system."  Thanks for the help btw.  Wish I could vote your answer up, but my rep is still too low on here.